# Do I need a hardware firewall even if I have Internet security software?

Tags: firewalls, antivirus

I have **Kaspersky Internet Security 2010** installed on my Win7 computer. I assume it gives me enough protection for a software firewall(port security,tracking tcp,udp traffic etc.)  Do I still need a hardware firewall for protection as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the software firewall on your machine is functioning correctly and that's the only device you need to protect, it could be that a hardware firewall isn't needed.

That said the advantage of having it as a separate device is that if your system is infected with malware or the software firewall malfunctions, it is a good defence-in-depth step option to have a completely separate device providing a layer of protection.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these tools provide some level of protection, but neither makes you safe. People who write malware or who actively attack systems know how to circumvent the protections you've put up and test their techniques against both.

So while each of these tools has it's place, neither should be assumed to protect you.  There are protections that a hardware firewall can offer that a software firewall can't. And vice-versa.